# How to turn on error messages in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I need to show the error on the front page instead of the error report.Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the two methods can be used

1.Changing mode into the "developer"

2.Rename local.xml.sample in pub/error directory to local.xml

Answer (score 5):

Try following methods to display error on screen:

**1. Set the Magento mode**

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

**2. Uncomment code**

> app/bootstrap.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**3. Rename File**

From:

> pub/errors/local.xml.sample

To:

> pub/errors/local.xml

Comment: Thankyou perfect solution

Answer (score 2):

**Hello,**

If you want to display PHP error then Go to `app/bootstrap.php` and uncomment Line No 10 and 11. And if you want to display error instead of error report then Go to `pub/error` directory and find `local.xml.sample` file and rename it to `local.xml`

**That's it.**

I hope this solution will help you.