# Error on unidentified on the system.log

Tags: magento2

I'm getting the next error but I don't know what does it cause or why does this happens:

```
[2018-01-11 16:08:25] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/ebj8qtas/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/View/Attributes.php on line 88 [] []
```

Comment: Refer [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/208153/61183) link to enable onscreen error reporting in Magento2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know when it occurs ?
Try to do a `composer install --ignore-platform-reqs` and check if you have setup upgrade to do.