# Why is my catalog configuration page blank?

Tags: admin, magento-2.2.1

In my admin, my catalog configuration page is completely blank. I have not edited any of the code for this page. I do have a custom frontend theme installed, however.

I have already flushed set the caches under `System > Cache Management`, reset browser cache, and checked the admin page in question in another browser.

I am using Magento 2.2.1.

[image]

Comment: Refer [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/208153) link to enable error reporting in Magento2.

Comment: Looks like an issue with one of the system.xml files in your instance most likley a 3rd party extension / theme i would recommend disabling all extensions and enabling 1 by one to determain which one is causing the issue or to save time you could edit the app/bootstrap.php and find #ini_set('display_errors', 1); and remove the # save and upload this should then display the errors on the page making easier to debug

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
php bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

delete everything in the var folder except .htaccess

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
php bin/magento index:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution is

```
chmod -R 777 /path/xxx.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Catalog
```

how to find solution is

first,go to see /var/log/system.log ,you will see something about "main.CRITICAL: Can't create directory",which means permission problem.