# Magento 2 Blank Screen Product Detail page

Tags: magento2, product, product-view, magento2.2.2

I added one product from Magento admin panel (Magento 2.2.2)

Cleared cache and indexing, Product appears in search and listing page and you can even add to cart from Listing page.

But when you click on the product and visit the product details page it gives the blank screen

In the network tab, it shows `status code 200` and in the page source, it shows the empty body.

There is nothing in `var/log/*` and `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

And i tried adding

```
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

in `index.php` at root folder

Comment: Check Magento log files under [document root]/var/log folder. There you can find some clue.

Comment: If nothing is found there, you need to check apache error logs on the server also.

Comment: sorry , i forgot to mention that there is nothing in  var/log/* and /var/log/apache2/error.log

Comment: Refer [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/208153) link.

Comment: try to add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in `index.php` of `pub ` directory, you can find it on `pub> index.php` and check

Comment: I think @PratikOza is correct.

Comment: still no luck  :-(

Comment: I'm having the same issue on a recent migrated Magento 2.1.12; as the case commented the products are shown on product listings and you can add it to the cart but receiving a blank page when accessing the product detail page. BTW no log errors shown neither in the exception.log nor the system.log. It's just happening with certain products, fortunately the most of them are working OK. Any idea would be more than welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I have been in similar kind of situation, I have migrated the data from magento 1.9.x to magento 2.2.8 and there was two website in magento, for the default website the product detail page was working fine but for the other website it was not, I was only able to see the blank page where noting rendered in body tag, with that, one thing was sure that it is a layout related issue as magento was unable to load the layout. After spending a day I finally found that in the secondary website layout was updated at product level but it is was also observed that you need to check updated layout in the website>store for the product. The main reason is that code of the layout in magento 1.9 was different to magento 2.x, so try to check layout updates.
This may help you in certain conditions only.

Answer (score 0):

1.Navigate to your MagentoDir on server or localhost via terminal or if you can open the file in a text editor like Notepad or sublime text.

2.Enter the following command and see the system log, it will contain the broken reference of the DOM/Product Details Page. This is mainly when you have changed your category_product_view.xml in a custom theme (trying to override the default template) or the default theme and it breaks the layout of the page.

```
tail -f var/log/system.log
```

if that dosen't give you any hints try the following:

```
tail -f var/log/exception.log   

tail -f var/log/debug.log
```

Hope you found it useful.