# Magento intallation error 500

Tags: magento2, http-error-500, error-log

I'm trying to install Magento 2.4.2-p-1 but I'm getting Internal Server Error 500
Note(I've already tried all these [options](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208043/how-to-turn-on-error-messages-in-magento-2) but No progress)
Please guide me it's my first time to start work on Magento 2.

Comment: Hi, I will give you some insights, but without some additional information I can do it effectively. Please, check if your web server is pointing to MAGENTO_ROOT/pub/index.php or MAGENTO_ROOT/index php. I am used to include a phpinfo() to make sure that the file is being loaded. You can also remove the comment out on app/bootstrap.php over ini_set('display_errors', true). It will must show the error that you are looking for. Please include more information on the question, like: web server config, log files; etc.

Answer (score 0):

In this two things like :-

**`First :-`**

Magento 2.4.2 now index.php file available in pub directory.So you can try your URL like :- **`http://localhost/magento242/pub/index.php`**.
If will not open you set error reporting like :- Go to your index.php and open and set **`ini_set('display_errors', true);`**

**`Second :-`**

It may be issue is permission or not run fully commands. So can run below commands like :-

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
```

I hope your issue solve. if any questions let me know

**`THANKS.`**